# No se muestran los estilos CSS en Github Pages de una página en específico

Tags: html, css, github, github-pages

Todas mis páginas muestran correctamente los estilos CSS excepto la siguiente, no sé qué puede ser. Parece que tengo las rutas relativas correctas, pero manda los siguientes errores la consola.

https://ozonemotion.github.io/alo-bomnito/html/agregar_productos.html

[image: Errores en GET]

Comment: Pon código no imágenes. Lee el [tour] y [ask] para recibir una mejor ayuda.

Comment: Estan mal las ruta a los CSS, por ejemplo, para `root.css` la ruta correcta es `https://ozonemotion.github.io/alo-bomnito/css/default/root.css`